# JQuery 1.8.1 TypeError: d is undefined When Using Spring Web MVC + Apache Tiles + JSPX

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, tiles

I'm new to JSPX and Tiles. My tiles definition (Tiles 2.2) is:

```
<tiles-definition>
  <definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/test.jspx" preparer="com.test.MenuPreparer">
  </definition>
</tiles-definition>
```

The content of my `test.jpsx` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"    
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags">     
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<spring:url value="/scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" var="jqURL" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="${jqURL}"><jsp:text /></script> 
</head>

<body>
<h1>TEST!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `servlet-context.xml`, I've included resources location:

```
<resources location="/resources/scripts/" mapping="/scripts/**" />
```

When I tried to view the page is Firefox 14.0.1, I find the following in Error Console:

```
TypeError: d is undefined
http://localhost:8080/test/scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js
```

When I view the same page in IE9, I got the following message in IE Console:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined
jquery-1.8.1.min.js, line 2 character 19451
```

JQuery won't work in both browsers.

But when I'm including the same JQuery script in standalone HTML (not deployed in tc Server), I got no error message in browser console and JQuery is working.

How to make JQuery works when using Spring Web MVC + Apache Tiles + JSPX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [Why does my simple strict XHTML file give errors when I include jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687777/why-does-my-simple-strict-xhtml-file-give-errors-when-i-include-jquery), I added following line to `test.jspx`:

```
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

And it's working now.