# An unexplainable space added inside an anchor

Tags: html, css, whitespace

This is a HTML snippet from my application:

```
Correct answers: 
0 / 6<br /><br />
You have failed to pass the final test.

<a href="/module/controller/course/id/5" class="accessible-link">
    Click here
</a> 
to return to the training.
```

As you can see, there is a single space after the `</a>` closing tag. Yet in the browser the space is added inside the anchor. So it looks like this:

[image]

This is the PHP code which produces the HTML:

```
<?php if (isset($this->correctAnswersCount) && isset($this->answersCount)): ?>
        <?php echo Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('Počet správnych odpovedí'); ?>:
        <?php echo ToHtml($this->correctAnswersCount); ?> / <?php echo ToHtml($this->answersCount); ?><br /><br />
<?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('Záverečný test sa vám nepodarilo úspešne absolvovať.'), "\n"; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo ToHtml($this->backToCourseUri); ?>" class="accessible-link">
            <?php echo Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('Kliknite'), "\n"; ?>
        </a>
        <?php echo Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('pre návrat do kurzu.'), "\n"; ?>
```

I am completely baffled by this and cannot figure out what's causing this even though I've been staring into the code for 30 minutes now.

This is a relevant part from the translation file:

```
'Kliknite' => 'Click here',
```

As you can see, there should be no space added by Zend_Translate.

Comment: Try HTML5, not XHTML. Albeit underlining the space within the `<a>` is standard behaviour for many browsers.

Comment: @mario there is no space. The linebreak and tabstop is just rendered as one. And I doubt it won't be there in HTML5 (which is tag soup anyway).

Comment: @mario I know that. But there is no space between <a> and </a>. The space is after the closing </a> tag.

Comment: Well actually, if you send xhtml without the correct mime type it's just tag soup to most browsers (trailing slashes are garbage). And html5 happens to define exactly such edge cases better.

Comment: It's not a problem to send XHTML with proper mime type. The only problematic browser is IE but IE9 is supposed to support XHTML so that should be solved soon.

Comment: Yes. But do you, or don't you? It's known to cause display differences if you use real XHTML (it's not just xml:space). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662508/html-4-html-5-xhtml-mime-types-the-definitive-resource

Comment: @mario Yes I do. I am sending xhtml+xml mime type. I also tried changin the doctype to HTML and serving it as HTML without any difference. The problem stays the same.

Comment: What browser? Internet Explorer was known to change the HTML (saving the HTML page to disk was different from what it got from the web server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
<a href="<?php echo ToHtml($this->backToCourseUri); ?>" class="accessible-link">
    <?php echo Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('Kliknite'), "\n"; ?>
</a>
```

Into this:

```
<a href="<?php echo ToHtml($this->backToCourseUri); ?>" class="accessible-link">
    <?php echo Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('Kliknite'), "\n"; ?></a>
```

The `</a>` should be in the same line after the `<?php echo Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('Kliknite'), "\n"; ?>` aka **Click Here**

The new line and the spaces after it renders like 1 space that is still inside the `<a></a>` tags, that is where the blank space is coming from.

For the record I also don't like the closing tag to be next to the content instead of a being in a new line but that's how it has to be done in order to work correctly.

I like good formatted code and I always look for an autoformat command in my IDE.

But at least for example in Visual Studio when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (the Format Document shorcut) the closing tags like the `</a>` are not automatically moved to a new line for this exact reason: that it should not break the way it looks before the auto format.

Comment: Yes, it works like that. But I would like to have opening tag, anchor and closing tag on separate lines in order to have cleaner HTML templates.

Comment: But you can't do it that way since **YOU** are the one that is putting the extra space in your code. The whitespaces ( the new line and the spaces after it) all become into one single space that is still inside the `<a></a>` tags. That's just how HTML works man

Comment: @Carlos actually it's the browsers that falsely put it there. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-line-breaks is clear on how this should be rendered. The issue is, due to indenting, there is also a tabstop between the linebreak and the closing element. In theory putting the closing a without indenting should fix that, but it doesnt (at least not in IE8 and FF3)

Comment: @Richard you're welcome. Google a bit for whitespace bugs in browsers. I am sure you will come across this one, too.

Comment: @Gordon: You are right. But as we know the browsers often don't follow exactly all the standards

Comment: At least in IE9, Firefox 3.6.12, Chrome 8, Opera 10.61 and Safari 5.0.1 they all render the same thing: The unwanted space

Answer (score 6):

Close the 'a' tag directly after the next, without a newline, like this:

```
<a href="/module/controller/course/id/5" class="accessible-link">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Yes, it works like that. But I would like to have opening tag, anchor and closing tag on separate lines in order to have cleaner HTML templates.

Comment: Which is where the space is coming from. The browser is confused by the whitespace and there is nothing you can do to clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<a href="/module/controller/course/id/5" class="accessible-link">Click here</a>
```

I am not sure if this will work, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Yes, it works like that. But I would like to have opening tag, anchor and closing tag on separate lines in order to have cleaner HTML templates.

Answer (score 0):

Put `&nbsp;` immediately after the `</a>` tag.