# Why does IE11 give this warning: HTML1406: Invalid tag start: "<?"

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml, doctype, internet-explorer-11

My pages are written and declared as XHTML 1.0 Strict. The first lines goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
```

Which I belive is correct for a XHTML 1.0 Strict but nevertheless IE11 gives this warning:

```
HTML1406: Invalid tag start: "<?". Question marks should not start tags. File: default.aspx, Line: 1, Column: 2
```

Anyone know if this is somthing I should worry about?

Comment: hmm you declaring the file as an xml file and after it as an HTML file, is this valid?

Comment: According to W3C: "An XML declaration is not required in all XML documents; however XHTML document authors are strongly encouraged to use XML declarations in all their documents" -  see [http://www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/normative.html)

Comment: Yes, but it's not required. So I suggest you remove the xml declaration. Keep in mind that the page was written in 2002.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that although you have created a file with an XHTML doctype you have served it using a `text/html` media type.

So IE11 (and other browsers) treat the file as an HTML file and parse it with their HTML parser. An XML declaration in an HTML file is invalid, and that's what the browser is telling you. If you had served the file with an `application/xhtml+xml` media type, the browser would have treated the file as XHTML and used its XML parser to parse it. Then the XML declaration would be handled correctly according the XML rules and IE11 would not give you that warning message.

There's no real problem here. The HTML parser will treat the declaration as a [bogus comment](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#bogus-comment-state) and just carry on regardless.

For more information you should read [Sending XHTML as text/html Considered Harmful](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml) and/or [HTML 4, HTML 5, XHTML, MIME types - the definitive resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662508/html-4-html-5-xhtml-mime-types-the-definitive-resource/2664082#2664082)

Answer (score 0):

If you got here because you're working on an old(er) `ASP.NET` `Web Forms` app/site... try turning on `Compatibility View`... that worked for me