# What is the difference between HTML's validation mode?

Tags: html, xslt, xhtml, xslt-1.0, transform

Please explain, when we use XLST1.0, what's key difference between any HTML validation mode: HTML 4.01, HTML5, XHTML 1.1, XHTML 1.0 Frameset, XHTML 1.0 Transitional, XHMLT5?

What features may be present when used transformation on Client or on Server side?

Is there any difference when working with various encodings or various Browser engines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML 4, HTML 5, XHTML, MIME types - the definitive resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662508/html-4-html-5-xhtml-mime-types-the-definitive-resource)

Comment: @TimT. Your question didn't mention operating system specifics.

Comment: @AhmedGaafer No. Question/answer linked by you is not about that at all.

Comment: @MrLister Sorry I wanted to say about different Browser engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for XSLT 1, if you want to generate HTML to be processed in a browser as text/html, use `xsl:output method="html"` and create your HTML elements in no namespace.

If you know you can or want restrict yourself to HTML 4.01 then you can use one of the HTML 4.01 document types in the `xsl:output` declaration for `doctype-system` (and additionally the adequate `doctype-public` if needed), if you want to produce HTML5 then in the XSLT use `xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"`.

That way your XSLT should generate HTML parseable by the modern browser's HTML soup parsers or HTML5 parsers.

Unless you know you want to serve XHTML to be parsed and processed by browsers as application/xml or application/xhtml+xml I wouldn't recommend trying to use XSLT 1 to produce XHTML.

Comment: Thanks for the "about:legacy-doctype" in html5 contex. I also found a description about that issue https://www.w3.org/html/wg/tracker/issues/54.